# How to prevent a blank space while removing \r\n using .rstrip()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I have the following list

```
listA=['farm', '\r\n']
```

When i write the following code to remove '\r\n'

```
listA = [x.rstrip() for x in listA]
```

The output i get is

```
['farm', '']
```

The ideal output i want is. How do i accomplish this

```
['farm']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listB = [x for x in listA if x.rstrip()]
```

Comment: More accurately, you may wish to use **listB = [x.rstrip() for x in listA if x.rstrip()]** - but this seems to be a bit overkill and inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` with `None` as first argument (instead of function name) and it will remove empty strings, empty lists, `None`. But it also removes integer `0` and float `0.0`

```
listA = ['farm', '']

listB = list(filter(None, listA))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: You solution doesn't remove `'\r\n'` from the original list.

Comment: @MykolaZotko no, it removes empty strings after `strip()` - see example data in code - result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to check whether the string contains only whitespace characters:

```
import re

listA = ['a   ', '\r\n', '']

listB = [i.rstrip() for i in listA if i and not re.match(r'\s+', i)]

print(listB)
# ['a']
```